# Dynamic Configuration with Laravel Horizon

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I am trying to change the mail driver's `username` and `password` on the fly like the following.

```
/**
* Execute the job.
*
* @return void
*/
public function handle()
{   
    config(['mail.username' => $this->username]);
    config(['mail.password' => $this->password]);

    Mail::to('me@me.com')->send(new OrderShipped());
}
```

The dynamic config setting was inside the queue job. For queue processing, I am using the Laravel horizon. But, when I execute the queue job. It's still using the default config. Not the config I set dynamically.

> Note: when I log right after config set it was showing the dynamic value.

How can I set the config dynamically and make Laravel horizon to use dynamic configuration?

Answer (score 0):

From [**Laravel version 7.x**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#sending-mail) onwards you can now state the mail driver to use while sending an email. All you need to configure all your connections & credentials properly in `app/config/mail.php`. Once configured, you can specify the name of the driver via `mailer()` function as below:

```
Mail::mailer('postmark')
    ->to($request->user())
    ->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle()
{
    config([
        'mail.username' => $this->username,
        'mail.password' => $this->password,
    ]);
    
}
```

I did it like that. I think the important part is that you get the data you will use in the Job class from outside.

```
public function __construct($username,$password)
{
    $this->username= $username;
    $this->receiver = $password;
    
}
```